# Extract pattern of letter foreward slash letter (e.g S/E) from string with regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I get no further with a supposedly simple problem:

My string:

```
string <- c("blabla S/E blabla", "blabla E/E bla", "E/S blabla")

[1] "S/E blabla" "E/E bla"    "E/S blabla"
```

**I want to**

extract : `S/E` `E/E` `E/S`: The pattern is a `letter` then `/` then again `letter`

using `str_extract` and `regex`

**My best try:**

```
str_extract(string, "[^A-Za-z][A-Za-z$]")

[1] "/E" "/E" "/S"
```

**Expected output:**

```
[1] "S/E" "E/E" "E/S"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could specify the pattern as upper case letter followed by a `/` followed by upper case letter

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "[A-Z]/[A-Z]")
[1] "S/E" "E/E" "E/S"
```

Comment: Ok. That was it. Maybe was just weird. Anyway thanks master!